# Kibana Visualize Data Table - Difference Between Aggregate Functions in a Separate Columns

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-7

Using Kibana 7.10.2 with the documents below, is there a way to compute a custom column that contains the difference between Min(value) and Max(value)?

```
{
  "_source": {
    "value": 10
  }
},
{
  "_source": {
    "value": 15
  }
}
```

Desired table structure

```
------------------
 Min | Max | Diff
------------------
  10 |  15 |  5
------------------
```

Min and Max are built-in functions under Metric Aggregations.
Is there a way to create a difference between two aggregate functions in a separate column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use TSVB that allows mathematical functions based on [tinymath](https://github.com/elastic/tinymath/blob/master/docs/functions.md). The downside is that currently exporting is not supported by TSVB.